# disable firebase Auth State Persistence

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this login function currently:

```
AuthorizationHome.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                ..........
```

But it basically keeps my session logged in even when I close my browser, restart my computer, it does it all. Because the user is able to manage their payments from my app, I need to make sure that if they close the browser, it logs them out.

Firebase docs tells me to do it like this:

```
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(() => {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

It is different then my original code, so I am not sure how to do this. I'm totally new to the way firebase works so I am a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to execute `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` after `AuthorizationHome.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` successfully resolves?

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(() => {
    return AuthorizationHome.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { /* do things */ });
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

That being said, you can probably run `setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)` as part of app initialization separately. It doesn't have to be run right before every execution of `doSignInWithEmailAndPassword`:

```
// app initialization
firebase
  .auth()
  .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)

// somewhere else on demand
AuthorizationHome.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: worked like a gem, I was able to use it on login, as that is best for this type of app in my opinion. I appreciate your detailed answer!